# db2 select statement from a table name where the table name is a variable

Tags: db2, count

I need to select all the table row count from a db2 database.

I have a query to select all the schema and table name:

```
select rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) as tableName from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'COM' order by tabname;
```

This query give me list of the table name of the database.

I would like to do something like:

```
select count(*) from tableFromTheFirstQuery
```

Where the tableFromThePreviousQuery is subsitute by the tableName of my first query.

I can not do like

```
select count(*) from (select rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) as tableName from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'COM' order by tabname);
```

I will only get result of count of my first query.

I am not sure the way is exist or not. Basically I need to save all the table row counts in a text file before doing DR activity.

Kindly advise

Comment: Use dynamic SQL. [PREPARE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000975.html), [EXECUTE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000948.html?view=kc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross-posted from SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725902/db2-select-statement-from-a-table-name-where-the-table-name-is-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a loop over the tables. From a sh in Linux you can do something like:

```
db2 connect to db
for t in $(db2 -x "select rtrim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname) from syscat,tables where tabschema = 'COM' order by tabname"); do
    db2 "select '$t', count(1) from $t"
done
```

-x removes headers and other info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a compound statement like this

```
CREATE TABLE COUNT_ROWS (
    TABSCHEMA  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   TABNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   ROW_COUNT   BIGINT
)
@
BEGIN
    FOR C AS cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO COUNT_ROWS SELECT ''' || TABSCHEMA || ''',''' || TABNAME || ''', COUNT(*) FROM '
            || '"' ||  TABSCHEMA || '"."' || TABNAME || '"' AS S
        FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
        WHERE TYPE = 'T' AND TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
        WITH UR
    DO
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C.S;
          COMMIT;
    END FOR;
END
@
SELECT * FROM COUNT_ROWS
@
```

Note that you will need to use `@` as your statement terminator to get the above to run